# POST request not populating body

Tags: javascript, express

I'm having trouble sending information from the client side to the server side.

In my application I have a form that I want to submit to my server. Because I am using a lib to auto generate my form from a json schema file, I'll have to manually submit the form, basically make a `post` request with my object. So far so good, however my request reaches the backend with an empty body.

Client post request:

```
const test = {
    name: "hello"
}
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/my-route/test", test)
    .then(res => console.log("res.data", res.data));
```

Server route definition

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors());

/* ... */

app.post("/my-route/:type", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.params.type) {
        res.send({
            err: "Please provide type"
        });
    } else {
        console.log('req.body', req.body);

        res.send({
            sucess: "Generating type " + req.params.type
        });
    }
});
```

My log on the backend generates `req.body {}` instead of `req.body { name: "hello" }`

If I decide to `JSON.stringify(test)`, then my log becomes `req.body { '{"name":"hello"}': '' }`, which is not really want I intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axios request is sending a JSON payload. However, your server isn't parsing JSON; it's only parsing URL-encoded bodies. You'll want to add this middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Because you don't have that parser, your `bodyParser.urlencoded(...)` middleware is populating `req.body` with just the empty object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution helped me to fetch req.body which was coming as undefined previously.